# Laravel 5 Documentation - route model binding

Tags: php, model-binding, laravel-5

I'm reading Laravel 5 documentation and have some problem with understanding route model binding.

I use example code from [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing)

So, I added line to RouteServiceProvider.php:

```
public function boot(Router $router)
{
    parent::boot($router);

    $router->model('user', 'App\User');
}
```

I added route:

```
Route::get('/profile/{user}', function(App\User $user)
{
    die(var_dump($user));
});
```

Default Laravel user model is used.

```
<?php namespace App;

 use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
 use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
 use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

 class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,    CanResetPasswordContract {

     use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
     protected $table = 'users';

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
     protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
     protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

 }
```

And I have MySQL table 'users'. When I go to URL http://blog.app/profile/1, I expect to see data for user with ID 1, but I don't understand how to get actual model values. Instead I see:

[image]

Is there any special methods for getting model values? Or did I miss something?

Comment: If you do `dd($user->name)` - what does that show?

Comment: Actually, there is a good point from @TheShiftExchange, because the model looks like is loaded correctly.

Comment: I got the exact same problem. I reported it to Laravel. It was working a few days ago!

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem here. You just get an empty instance of `App\User`, since you declared that in your `Route::get()`. The model is never loaded.

Another way to bind model to the parameter:

```
Route::bind('user', function($value)
{
    return App\User::find($value);
});
```

The Closure you pass to the bind method will receive the value of the URI segment, and should return an instance of the class you want to be injected into the route.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem.
Look for the "$namespace" var in the "RouteServiceProvider" and try to set it blank :

```
protected $namespace = '';
```